# Replacement for column_names when using Mongoid with rails 3 and dry_crud

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dry, mongoid

I've been doing a spike on Rails 3 and Mongoid and with the pleasant memories of the auto scaffolding in Grails I started to look for a DRY view for ruby when I found:
http://github.com/codez/dry_crud

I created a simple class

```
class Capture 
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :species, :type => String
  field :captured_by, :type => String
  field :weight, :type => Integer
  field :length, :type => Integer

  def label
      "#{name} #{title}"
  end

  def self.column_names
    ['species', 'captured_by', 'weight', 'length']  
  end
end
```

But since dry_crud depends on self.column_names and the class above doesn't inherit from ActiveRecord::Base I have to create my own implementation for column_names like the one above. I would like to know if it possible to create a default implementation returning all of the fields above, instead of the hard coded list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short of injecting a new method in Mongoid::Document you can do this in your model.

```
self.fields.collect { |field| field[0] }
```

**Update** : Uhm better yet, if you fell adventurous.

In the model folder make a new file and name it model.rb

```
class Model
  include Mongoid::Document
  def self.column_names
    self.fields.collect { |field| field[0] }
  end
end
```

Now your model can inherit from that class instead of include Mongoid::Document. **capture.rb** will look like this

```
class Capture < Model
  field :species, :type => String
  field :captured_by, :type => String
  field :weight, :type => Integer
  field :length, :type => Integer

  def label
      "#{name} #{title}"
  end
end
```

Now you can use this natively for any model.

```
Capture.column_names
```

Comment: I might try using that myself actually.

Comment: Works like a charm but dry_crud won't work as soon as I add a references_one :species

Answer (score 4):

Why would you go through the trouble of doing all that when there's an in-built method?

**For Mongoid:**

```
Model.attribute_names
# => ["_id", "created_at", "updated_at", "species", "captured_by", "weight", "length"]
```