# How get all column names of model in Mongoid

Tags: ruby, mongoid

How can I get all column names from a `Mongoid` model in Rails?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use

> Model.fields.keys

Replace Model with your model name

Answer (score 1):

```
self.fields.collect { |field| field[0] }
```

As described here:
[Replacement for column_names when using Mongoid with rails 3 and dry_crud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669991/replacement-for-column-names-when-using-mongoid-with-rails-3-and-dry-crud)

Answer (score 0):

**For Mongoid:**

```
Model.attribute_names
```

---

**For ActiveRecord:**

```
Model.column_names
```

Answer (score -1):

MongoDB doesn't have columns, so your question is a bit meaningless.